# I get double entries for equally marked \index entries. how do I avoid that?

Tags: indexing

I entered this code `\index[p]{Dionigi di Alicarnasso!\textit{De Isaeo}!19|textit}` three times in my text and get in the index

```
Dionigi di Alicarnasso
De Isaeo
19, 39
De Isaeo
19, 38, 41
```

Why don't I get only

```
Dionigi di Alicarnasso
De Isaeo
19, 38, 39, 41
```

I get this problem in at least three instances similar to this. I'm using

```
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=n, title=Nomi di persone e luoghi] 
\makeindex[name=p, title=Passi citati nel testo]

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: spurious space in one of the entries?

Comment: The spaces Florian mentions could be linebreaks

Comment: What's the `19` in the entry?

Comment: I'm using \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}, but the all thing is quite long to copy here I believe. I have checked for spaces but it looks to me like there isn't any spurious :(  I also have this case: Erodoto\index[n]{Erodoto} (2.25)\index[p]{Erodoto!2!25|textit} where the first entry goes rightly into the proper index, the following one does not. the 19 above would be the my third level of "subindexing", which is the paragraph of the text of the ancient source quoted. Thank you very much!